# diving a string depending on a variable

Tags: python, dictionary

I have a piece of code (that was kindly written by someone from stackoverflow) which separates conditions based on a time variable:

```
factors = {"factor 1" : "10 minutes",
"factor 2" : "2 minutes",
"factor 3" : "8 minutes",
"factor 4" : "20 minutes",
"factor 5" : "7 minutes"
}

wantedTime = 19;
String_1={}
String_2={}
total = 0
for k,v in factors.items():## or factors.iteritems()
    time = int(v.split(" ")[0])
    if total+time <= wantedTime:
        total +=time
        String_1[k]=v
    else:
        String_2[k]=v
```

However, it always seems to select the same variables for the first string. For instance if i run this script 5 times where i want 19 minutes worth of variables, it always splits them in the same way. What I want is for it to be randomised:

so sometimes it selects factor 4, sometimes it selects factors 1 and 3.

Thank you in advance

Comment: use `for k in list(factors.keys())[randint(0, 1000)%len(factors)]:` and `v = factors[k]` :)

Comment: I like the honesty (that you admit that the code was written by someone on this site), but don't you think that you should _try to learn something as well_?

Comment: How do you conclude it always goes into the first branch? On third iteration it will execute the `else` part.

Comment: @BartoszKP I think he implies that he doesn't want the same order from factors when adding up the time. He'd like `10+8` one time, and `10+7+2` another.

Comment: Torxed, thank you for your help! Devnull, please do not comment on these posts if you do not know the answer - it is most unhelpful.

Comment: @user2466084 Hey, don't be so rude. He's far more experienced than you and you know it. He only gives you an advice, and i agree with him.

Comment: Rude! I think devnul was the rude one. I make absolutely no claim to be experienced. Indeed, if I were, I wouldn't be asking these simple questions on stackoverflow would I? Luckily, most people on this website are happy to help and I am grateful to those that do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Converted my comment into an answer for the sake of it.

```
from random import randint
factors = {"factor 1" : "10 minutes",
"factor 2" : "2 minutes",
"factor 3" : "8 minutes",
"factor 4" : "20 minutes",
"factor 5" : "7 minutes"
}

wantedTime = 19;
String_1={}
String_2={}
total = 0
for k in list(factors.keys())[randint(0, 1000)%len(factors)-1]:
    v = factors[k]
    time = int(v.split(" ")[0])
    if total+time <= wantedTime:
        total +=time
        String_1[k]=v
    else:
        String_2[k]=v
```

Answer (score 3):

I think you can just shuffle the iterable:

```
import random

for k, v in sorted(factors.items(), key=lambda k: random.random()):
```